# merge two fetching objects to send response to react in node js with mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am new to node.js Now I want to send a response to client-side. I have two collections, In one collections  I have all the details. In another collection, I have some more details, Now I want to send all these two collections to the collections, I had tried to merge two collections, but it's not working

**My Sample Code**

```
router.route('/backend/deptwise').post(function(req, res, next) {
        const { event_name, dept } = req.body;
        Reguser.find({ eventname: event_name, dept: dept }, (err, docs) => {
            if (docs.length) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < docs.length; i++){
                    WholeReg.find({ reg_id: docs[i].reg_id }, (err, docs1) => {
                        /// Logic for merging  `docs1[0].teamname` with docs
                    });
                    if (docs.length - 1 == i) {
                        res.send(docs);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                res.send('No Events Found');
            }
        });
    });
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this. I don't have a choice, I really want to merge two fetching objects in node js to send a response to react js,
please help me to solve 
Thanks and regards, Balaji Rajendran

Comment: Do some research around `mongodb aggregation`, it might help you.

Comment: If you need to use aggregation way please share sample data for creating aggregation relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import _ from 'lodash'

router.route('/backend/deptwise').post(async (req, res, next) => {
    const { event_name, dept } = req.body;
    const regusers =  await Reguser.find({ eventname: event_name, dept: dept })
    if (regusers.length) {
        const results = []
        const allUser = _.map(regusers, async reguser => {
            const wholeRegs = await WholeReg.findOne({ reg_id: reguser.reg_id })
            const result = _.merge(reguser, wholeRegs)
            results.push(result)
        })
        Promise.all(allUser)
        res.send(results);
    } else {
        res.send('No Events Found');
    }
});
```

This will solve your problem but I thing you should go for aggregation. It is easy, clean syntax and efficient more than that.

Comment: After merging two objects its shows the result correct. But In `res.send` its return empty result

Comment: console.log(results) if result is correct after promise.all then res.send({ results }) will work. please let me know if it is not.